# In android the second time I call an alert dialog it forces closed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have some code to use an alert dialog to add stuff to a database. this works, but only the first time I use it. The second time I press the button to open the alert dialog it force closes.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(EmergencyDb.this);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(EmergencyDb.this);
        alert1.setTitle("New Contact");
        alert1.setMessage("Name: ");
        alert2.setTitle("New Contact");
        alert2.setMessage("Phone Number: ");

        final EditText input1 = new EditText(EmergencyDb.this);
        final EditText input2 = new EditText(EmergencyDb.this);
        final int PHONE_TYPE = 3;
        input2.setInputType(PHONE_TYPE);
        alert1.setView(input1);
        alert2.setView(input2);
        alert1.setPositiveButton("Next", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                name = input1.getText().toString();
                alert2.show();

                  }
                });

        alert2.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                phoneNum = input2.getText().toString();
                SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                openHelper.addContact(name, phoneNum, db);
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try {
                    cursor = getContactCursor();
                    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(EmergencyDb.this,
                            R.layout.row, cursor, COLUMNS, VIEWS);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    //... error handling
                }

                  }
                });

        alert1.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // Canceled.
              }
            });

        alert2.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // Canceled.
              }
            });
        final Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                alert1.show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "force close".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in final access modifier? However, check your logcat to find the answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to `dismiss()` or `cancel()` the alerts before you show another one or things could get confused. Add a call to `dialog.cancel()` in the `onClick` methods.

```
alert1.setPositiveButton("Next", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                name = input1.getText().toString();
                dialog.cancel(); alert2.show();

                  }
                });
```

Let me know if that works.